# Как с помощью JSTL вывести Коллекцию объектов и их параметров?

Tags: java, jstl

ObjectEntity.java

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQueries;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "nc_object")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "getObjectsByObjectType", query = "from ObjectEntity oe where oe.objectType = :objectType"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "getObjectsByParent", query = "from ObjectEntity oe where oe.parent = :parent")
})
public class ObjectEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3720088500236365064L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "object_id")
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "object_name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "object_type")
    private ObjectType objectType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private ObjectEntity parent;

    @Transient
    private List<ParamEntity> paramEntityList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Transient
    private List<AttributeEntity> attributeEntityList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ObjectEntity() {
    }

    public ObjectEntity(String id, String name, ObjectType objectType, ObjectEntity parent) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.objectType = objectType;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public ObjectEntity(String name, ObjectType objectType, ObjectEntity parent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.objectType = objectType;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public ObjectEntity(String name, ObjectType objectType) {
        this.name = name;
        this.objectType = objectType;
    }

    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ObjectType getObjectType() {
        return objectType;
    }

    public void setObjectType(ObjectType objectType) {
        this.objectType = objectType;
    }

    public ObjectEntity getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(ObjectEntity parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public List<ParamEntity> getParamEntityList() {
        return paramEntityList;
    }

    public void setParamEntityList(List<ParamEntity> paramEntityList) {
        this.paramEntityList = paramEntityList;
    }

    public List<AttributeEntity> getAttributeEntityList() {
        return attributeEntityList;
    }

    public void setAttributeEntityList(List<AttributeEntity> attributeEntityList) {
        this.attributeEntityList = attributeEntityList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "object {" +
                "name=" + name + ", " +
                "type=" + objectType.toString() + ", " +
                "parent=" + (parent != null ? parent.toString() : "not parent") +
                "}";
    }
}
```

Он содержит коллекцию paramEntityList:

ParamEntity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "nc_params")
@IdClass(ParamPk.class)
@org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "getParamForObject", query = "from ParamEntity pe where pe.objectId = :id")
})
public class ParamEntity implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1749537130852076187L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "object_id")
    private ObjectEntity objectId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "attribute_id")
    private AttributeEntity attributeId;

    @Column(name = "string_value")
    private String stringValue;

    @Column(name = "number_value")
    private Integer numberValue;

    @Column(name = "date_value")
    private Date dateValue;

    @JoinColumn(name= "reference_value")
    @ManyToOne
    private ObjectEntity objectEntityValue;

    public ParamEntity() {
    }

    public ParamEntity(ObjectEntity objectId, AttributeEntity attributeId, String stringValue, Integer numberValue, Date dateValue, ObjectEntity objectEntityValue) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
        this.attributeId = attributeId;
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
        this.numberValue = numberValue;
        this.dateValue = dateValue;
        this.objectEntityValue = objectEntityValue;
    }

    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public ObjectEntity getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(ObjectEntity objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public AttributeEntity getAttributeId() {
        return attributeId;
    }

    public void setAttributeId(AttributeEntity attributeId) {
        this.attributeId = attributeId;
    }

    public String getStringValue() {
        return stringValue;
    }

    public void setStringValue(String stringValue) {
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }

    public Integer getNumberValue() {
        return numberValue;
    }

    public void setNumberValue(Integer numberValue) {
        this.numberValue = numberValue;
    }

    public Date getDateValue() {
        return dateValue;
    }

    public void setDateValue(Date dateValue) {
        this.dateValue = dateValue;
    }

    public ObjectEntity getObjectEntityValue() {
        return objectEntityValue;
    }

    public void setObjectEntityValue(ObjectEntity objectEntityValue) {
        this.objectEntityValue = objectEntityValue;
    }
```

В контроллере получаю коллекцию таких объектов и передаю в представление:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Club")
public class ClubController {

    public static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ClubController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ObjectService objectService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getClubs(Model model) {
        log.info("view Clubs...");
        List<ObjectEntity> objectEntities = objectService.getObjectByTypeName("Club");
        model.addAttribute("clubList", objectEntities);
        return "club/view";
    }

}
```

Пытаюсь вывести в цикле, но не отображаются значения, хотя пустых полей создается по количеству параметров. Т.е на месте параметра `${param.stringValue}` пусто:

```
<%@include file="../header.jsp"%>

<h2>Clubs</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="club" items="${clubList}">
            <tr>
                <c:forEach var="param" items="${club.paramEntityList}">
                    <th><a href="/lab5/Club/${club.id}">${param.stringValue}</a></th>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
<%@include file="../footer.jsp"%>
```

Через логи выводил значения всех атрибутов, так что из базы данных я все получаю, а вот как это вывести на JSP странице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что переменная цикла имеет то же имя, что и неявный объект `param`, хранящий параметры запроса. Но его нельзя перекрыть, поэтому в теле цикла происходит обращение не к переменной цикла, а к глобальному объекту. Так как последний не имеет метода `getStringValue`, вы получаете пустое место. Просто используйте другое имя для переменной цикла:

```
<c:forEach var="paramEntity" items="${club.paramEntityList}">
    <th><a href="/lab5/Club/${club.id}">${paramEntity.stringValue}</a></th>
</c:forEach>
```

P.S. Немного странно, что у вас в `tbody` используется `th` и что количество колонок в каждой строке разное.

Comment: Не подумал про глобальные переменные, это мое незнание. Правильно, вместо th > td. А количество колонок одинаковое, у объекта который я тяну с базы, два параметра, это имя и город. И спасибо вам за помощь)